# Quickening Video Processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, memory-management, video-processing

I am using Matlab for a position tracking application wherein the position is extracted frame by frame from a ~20 minute .avi file. Right now to process a 20 minute video takes ~1 hour. The annoying thing is that the actual algorithmic computations are quite fast. The bottleneck is simply LOADING the .avi frames into Matlab, which we do 20 frames at a time. Here is our pseudocode:

```
vidobj = VideoReader(vidFile);
frmStep=20; %# of frames to load at a time
for k=1:frmStep:(numFrames-frmStep+1)
   f = read(vidobj, [k (k+frmStep-1)]); 
   %%Do video processing
end
```

I was wondering whether there was any way to load this faster or do anything about the horribly long computation times....

Answer (score 0):

Over the years I have tried a couple of alternatives to Matlab's native video processing procedures but I never profiled them so I can't tell you anything about the speed up.

The first alternative I've used extensively was [mmread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread). This function uses ffmpeg to do the actual frame grabbing.

Currently I use the VideoCapture class in mexopencv. You will need opencv installed for that to compile. I have also managed to get most of the Matlab bindings in opencv3 to compile (on Mac OSX), which also gives you a VideoCapture class.